# How to achieve multi-tenant databases in mongoDB using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on the backend for my app, what im looking to acomplish is create multi-tenant databases. I'm using MongoDB and mongoose. What i've found is there's 2 advisable ways to achieve this:

1. Same database for all clients (recommended for thousands of tenants)
2. Different databases for each client(recommended for hundreds of tenants)

I went for number 2, but after reviewing docs still can't figure it out.
Ive used this 2 links as guidance:

https://dev.to/przpiw/nodejs-mongodb-multi-tenant-app-by-example-435n
https://medium.com/brightlab-techblog/multitenant-node-js-application-with-mongoose-mongodb-f8841a285b4f

What i need is:

1. Call /auth route from front-end
2. Look up in master_database for tenant businessId,
3. Connect to respective business database

What i did is:

1. use mongoose.createConnection() to 'master_database' and buffer 'Tenant' model in it.
2. after route /auth runs, it checks for client businessId and create a new connection, but this time using mongoose.connect() to respective business.
3. Then it logs-in using loginUser function.

I expected it to login, and it does, but inside the app other routes are no longer working, connection is lost somehow. it logs-in but nothing else.

```
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config()
require('dotenv').config({ path: './env' })
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { loginUser } = require('./controllers/auth');
const { default: mongoose } = require('mongoose');
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
const Tenant = require('./models/tenants');

const app = express();

let db;
try {
    db = mongoose.createConnection(`mongodb+srv://.../master_database`);
    console.log('Succesful connection')
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error('Error initializing DB')

}
const TenantSchema = Schema({

            email:{
                type: String,
            },
        
            businessId: {
                type: String,
            },
        
            state: {
                type: String,
            }
        
        })
const Tenant = db.model('Tenant', TenantSchema)

app.use(cors());
app.use( express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

//Review user and connect to corresponding DB
app.post('/api/auth' , async (req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body
        try {
            const { businessId } = await Tenant.findOne({email}).exec();
       mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://.../${businessId}`)
       loginUser(req , res)
      
} 
);

//Routes

app.use(express.json())
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/api/clients', require('./routes/clients'));
app.use('/api/orders', require('./routes/orders'));
... (more routes)

app.listen( process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Running on port: ${ process.env.PORT }`)

});
```

I'm still missing in the code how to handle the logout and login again, it should check if connection to any business database have been made. If a user logs-in, check if businessId is the same as the already created database connection, otherwise change database connection.

Maybe the issue is on using mongoose.connect() after createConnection() ?, the other approach i tried is use connect() to master_database (as first connection) and then to secondary database using createConnection(),  but  in that case i'll need to buffer all models in this and it will be tedious.

I'll appreciate a bit of guidance on how connect() and createConnection() work

PD: This is my first question so i apologize in advance if structure is not appropiate. Thank u all

Answer (score 1):

I achieved what i wanted, here i post the code.. feel free to add any comment.

```
let tenantConnection = undefined; // Added a track variable of the db name

    app.post('/api/auth' , async (req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body
try {
    const { businessId } = await Tenant.findOne({ email }).exec();
     
    if (tenantConnection === businessId) {
     
      loginUser(req, res);
    } else {
    
      if (tenantConnection) {
        mongoose.connections[0].close()
        tenantConnection = businessId; // Remove from tracking
        await dbConnection(businessId);
      } else {
        await dbConnection(businessId);
        tenantConnection = businessId;
      }

      loginUser(req, res);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
     
} 
);
```